# Import Bulk Json to Firebase

Tags: firebase

1. How can import the bulk json files to firebase using REST API.
2. Is their any document or example for search in firebase.
3. Is every search query string is saved in the firebase as file.

Answer (score 1):

Consult the Firebase [REST API Quickstart](https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/quickstart.html) and [REST API Docs](https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/api/) for examples of how to upload / import JSON and interact with the JSON store.

Comment: Hi, I want to import bulk json, for example 1000 json at a time. how it is possible in that document , we add/update json one by one. but i need bulk import.

Comment: Simply combine all 1000 objects into a single JSON file and then POST, PUT or PATCH that file, depending on the format and your requirements.

Comment: What happens when you get an error on one object but not the others when they're combined in a single JSON file? Do you get multiple errors or just one? Do they all fail or just the single one? I can't find any info in the Firebase docs on this.

Comment: @Rachel Once it encounters the first error indicating malformed JSON, parsing the JSON will be aborted and the first error will be returned.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to put a JSON file in firebase, go to your database add a node and paste the JSON there as its value. Firebase will parse it automatically.

Comment: You don't have to add a node and don't have to copy&paste. Just go to your database, click the "..." on the top-right, and select "Import JSON".

Comment: @ErelSegal-Halevi programmatically? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56401731/import-json-file-from-firebase-admin-sdk

Comment: As with literally everything else related to firebase, there is no documentation on basic tasks. What is a "node"? There is no "..." with an option to "import json"?