# Import json file from Firebase Admin SDK

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

I can update the whole database (Real Database) by importing a json file in Firebase Console:

[image]

How can I do it programmatically from server side (with Firebase Admin)?

I tried

```
private void uploadFirebaseDatabaseFile(JsonObject jsonObject) {
    // As an admin, the app has access to read and write all data, regardless of Security Rules
    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    ref.setValue(jsonObject, (error, ref1) -> System.out.println(error + " " + ref1));
}
```

But it throws `java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException ... Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not a JSON Primitive: { ...`

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of [Importing Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38764273/how-do-i-import-json-files-to-firebase-without-importing-manually)?

Comment: @Jay no, there is no such method like `ref.set()` in Firebase Admin Java SDK

Comment: @Jay there is only `setValue` which expects a primitive type and not a json object or path to json file...

Answer (score 0):

Solved it:

```
private void uploadFirebaseDatabaseFile(Gson gson, JsonObject jsonObject) throws Exception {
    // As an admin, the app has access to read and write all data, regardless of Security Rules
    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    CountDownLatch done = new CountDownLatch(1);
    // we must convert our JsonObject and its all nested children to Map<String, Object>
    ref.setValue(gson.fromJson(jsonObject, Map.class), (error, ref1) -> {
            System.out.println(error + " " + ref1);
        done.countDown();
    });
    done.await();
}
```